# How do I handle this HUGE Firefox 83 memory leak?

Tags: linux, firefox, memory, memory-leaks, memory-limit

Whenever I leave Firefox on, with a bunch of tabs, for more than a few hours, its memory use balloons, and everything else seems to be swapped out, so my system becomes highly non-responsive. In a typical case, it will have a child process named WebExtensions which takes up 27 GB of virtual memory. I think it might be this bug:

[Very high virtual memory usage in the WebExtensions process on Linux](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1615988)

but I'm not sure. Anyway, my question is: What can I/should I do to either make Firefox leak less memory; hard-limit the amount of virtual memory it uses; or as a last resort, auto-restart it when it hits a certain memory use threshold?

Information about my system:

- Firefox 83.0
- Devuan GNU/Linux Beowulf (= Debian Buster without systemd)
- Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 (bundled with Devuan)
- Physical RAM: 16 GB.
- Output of `top` for the two relevant processes (*not* while experiencing the non-responsiveness; hmm...):

  ```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  9616 eyalroz   20   0   26.7g 310316 142716 S   5.6   1.9   8:32.19 WebExtensions
  9472 eyalroz   20   0 3845772   1.0g 322156 S   0.0   6.6  27:26.37 firefox-bin
  ```

Comment: Um, but what’s the actual problem? Due to the way virtual memory works on Linux, huge virtual memory “use” is not at all strange and also not _memory use_. I observe the same with InfluxDB, Serviio, Grafana, PolicyKit, Docker, Grafana, dnscrypt-proxy, GitLab Runner, …

Comment: @DanielB: All other processes get swapped out and the system becomes terribly unresponsive

Comment: That will _never_ happen due to virtual memory size. Please provide all the figures of Firefox and the system totals.

Comment: @DanielB: Which figures? I added my physical memory size.

Comment: Virtual memory size, resident memory size, shared memory size of all Firefox processes and the output of `free -m`.

Comment: @DanielB: Ok, I'll post those next time I encounter the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably say to use an addon to unload the tabs after an amount of time.

I have been using [Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/) to "sleep" tabs and reduce memory usage. It will simply unload the tabs, free up memory and halt any scripts that may be using memory or the CPU. You can configure the timeout or manually trigger sleep on all tabs other than the one you are looking at.

You can also whitelist tabs that you never want to be put to sleep. Tabs that are sleeping will have a  emoji applied for this particular addon.

Selecting the tab will immediately reload the tab, from experience it is mostly instant with some slight reloading.

Comment: Just installed it. We'll see what effect this has.

Comment: Oh, this looks interesting. Thanks. I've only got a 4GB laptop and FF uses a big chunk of that.

Comment: On a machine with about 20 tabs my memory use went from about 2-2.5GB down to about 800MB @DavidPostill so it can definitely help. Depends if you mind things stopping when you're not looking at it. Edge has this functionality built in now.

Comment: It's better (as in quicker) even without things stopping ... I can't explain that one.

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak might be in some extension, rather than in Firefox itself.

To check, start Firefox in Troubleshoot/Safe mode, by the menu entry Help,
then "Troubleshoot Mode…" and click "Restart".

If the problem disappears, locate the troublesome extension by selectively
disabling extensions in `about:addons`.

Comment: My money is on Firefox itself - like a gas, it expands to fill all available space...  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: But does it expand beyond available space? :-(